# How to find a process that accesses sound hardware or communicates with the sound infrastructure?

Tags: linux, audio

I am using Arch based Linux using KDE.

Is there any command that I can use to find a process that accesses sound hardware or communicates with the sound infrastructure ?

The purpose is:

To locate a hidden process which is playing a sound on my computer - I have no idea what is causing the sound. There is no way to shutdown the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
lsof | grep /dev/snd
```